# Edit XML Split Output

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am working on splitting 1 large XML document into multiple ones based on a certain tag using the following code. However, the results given by the output have a defect.

Here is the structure of the large XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
  <project>
    <projectNumber>738951</projectNumber>
    <projectType>CHANGE REQUEST</projectType>
    <lineOfBusiness>COMMERCIAL</lineOfBusiness>
    ...
    </project>
</projects>
```

Here is my code to split:

```
# import module
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# read large XML and get root
xml = ET.parse("xmlbulk_SmartFill_SplitFill.xml")
root = xml.getroot()
print(root)

# set output document counter
counter = 1

# get child nodes for each project
for child in list(root):
    if child.tag.startswith('project'):
        src = ET.Element('project')
        src.append(child)
        with open(f'Project_{counter}.xml','w') as f:
            f.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>')
            tree = ET.ElementTree(src)
            tree.write(f,encoding="unicode")
        counter += 1
```

and here is the output (shown for 1 project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><project><project>
    <projectNumber>738951</projectNumber>
    <projectType>CHANGE REQUEST</projectType>
    <lineOfBusiness>COMMERCIAL</lineOfBusiness>
    <projectStatus>CLOSED</projectStatus>
```

The error is the 2  tags to the right of the header.
How can i:

1. remove 1 of the tags, and
2. move the remaining tab to be under the header.

My desired output would be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project>
    <projectNumber>738951</projectNumber>
    <projectType>CHANGE REQUEST</projectType>
    <lineOfBusiness>COMMERCIAL</lineOfBusiness>
    <projectStatus>CLOSED</projectStatus>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: Should it not better look like: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project>
    <projectNumber>738951</projectNumber>
    <projectType>CHANGE REQUEST</projectType>
    <lineOfBusiness>COMMERCIAL</lineOfBusiness>
    <projectStatus>CLOSED</projectStatus>
</project>

Comment: right -- with the closing project node at the end.

Comment: To get meaningful help you will need to edit your question and add a sample of the larger file containing TWO projects, and the exact expected 2 file output given that sample.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: apologies! see above for updates post.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create new elements using `ET.Element('project')`. Just write each existing `project` element to a separate file.

Here is compact code that does what you want:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for counter, project in enumerate(root, 1):
    ET.ElementTree(project).write(f"Project_{counter}.xml",
                                  xml_declaration=True,
                                  encoding="UTF-8")
```

---

This is the test input document I used:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects>
  <project>
    <projectNumber>738951</projectNumber>
    <projectType>CHANGE REQUEST</projectType>
    <lineOfBusiness>COMMERCIAL</lineOfBusiness>
  </project>
  <project>
    <projectNumber>123456</projectNumber>
    <projectType>CHANGE REQUEST 2</projectType>
    <lineOfBusiness>COMMERCIAL 2</lineOfBusiness>
  </project>
</projects>
```

Output in Project_1.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
    <projectNumber>738951</projectNumber>
    <projectType>CHANGE REQUEST</projectType>
    <lineOfBusiness>COMMERCIAL</lineOfBusiness>
  </project>
```

Output in Project_2.xml:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
    <projectNumber>123456</projectNumber>
    <projectType>CHANGE REQUEST 2</projectType>
    <lineOfBusiness>COMMERCIAL 2</lineOfBusiness>
  </project>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. However, those 2 <project> nodes to the right of the header are still showing. Any idea why? Here is the output with your code: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><project><project>
    <projectNumber>738951</projectNumber>
    <projectType>CHANGE REQUEST</projectType>
    <lineOfBusiness>COMMERCIAL</lineOfBusiness>

Comment: No, that is not what I get. See updated answer.